# MVC .Net 4 Razor Problems using <text> tag

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my code:

```
<text>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
    @foreach (var script in Model.Content.StartupScripts)
    {
        @script
    }    
    </script>
</text>
```

@script contains a javascript script, but this gets rendered by razor as:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">    
    {
            {
                var instanceId = &#39;blah&#39;;
                new RequestQueue(&#39; blah
       // etc
```

So...it looks like the  tag is not applying to the @script variable because single quotes are being replaced with &#39;. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to insert the raw text, MVC is trying to protect you from inserting rogue text that is trying to be script / html

Comment: ie, its escaping all the text being inserted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MVC is automatically encoding all output, you need to force it to display raw text.  You can do that with `@Html.Raw(script)` HTML helper.